# Addressing multiple B200 devices through the UHD API

Tags: usrp, uhd

I have 2 B210 radios on USB3 on a Windows 10 system using the UHD USRP C API latest release and Python 3.6 as the programming environment.  I can "sort of" run them simultaneously in separate processes but would like to know if it is possible to run them in a single thread?  How?

1 Happy to move to Linux if it makes things easier, I'm just more familiar with Windows.

2 "sort of" = I sometimes get errors which might be the two processes colliding somewhere down the stack.

The code below illustrates the race condition, sometimes one or both processes fail with error code 40 (UHD_ERROR_ASSERTION) or occasionally code 11 ( UHD_ERROR_KEY )

```
from ctypes import (windll, byref, c_void_p, c_char_p)
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process

def pread(argstring):
    # get handle for device
    usrp = c_void_p(0)  
    uhdapi = windll.uhd
    p_str=c_char_p(argstring.encode("UTF8"))
    errNo = uhdapi.uhd_usrp_make(byref(usrp),p_str) 
    if errNo != 0: 
        print("\r*****************************************************************")
        print("ERROR: ",errNo," IN: ",  current_process())
        print("=================================================================")
    if usrp.value != 0:
        uhdapi.uhd_usrp_free(byref(usrp))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        p2 = Process(target=pread, args=("",))
        p1 = Process(target=pread, args=("",))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        print("end")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple `multi_usrp` handles.

By the way, note that UHD is natively C++, and the C API is just a wrapper around that. It's designed for generating scripting interfaces like the Python thing you're using (don't know which interface between Python and the C API you're using – something self-written?).

While it's possible, there's no good reason to call the `recv` and `send` functions from the same thread – most modern machines are multi-threaded, and you should make use of that. Real-time SDR is a CPU-intensive task and you should use all the CPU resources available to get data to and from the driver, as to avoid overflowing buffers.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I saw multi_usrp in the C++ documentation but it is not clear to me how the argument string should be built if I have more than one device.  I tried comma separated serial nos but it only appeared to give me the last device  Is there an example you could point me to? 
I'm also a little cautious because what I have seen of multi unit use refers to the N200 series not the B200 and my naive first attempts at running two devices on the same machine are causing unexpected behaviour: threads locking up or terminating quietly. The python wrapper is my own - the problems also maybe?

Comment: As said, for the B200 you need multiple multi_usrp objects. For the N200, you can have multiple N200 per multi_usrp.

Comment: OK I understand now.  I read it as "can" not "must".  I have tried both ways.  When I try to create separate handles for 2 B210's  multiple LIBUSB errors are thrown when the second one is created.  I have tried in a single thread and separate threads.
`UHD Error:
    libusb_session_impl::libusb_event_handler_task: LIBUSB_ERROR_CODE -1`

Comment: That looks like a complicated libusb error, possibly unrelated to what you're doing. In any case, this is impossible to assess without you adding the important parts of your source code to your question!

Comment: I have added code in the question to illustrate the possible collision between processes when both are using the UHD API.